How do I observe when a list stored in another class changes to update my Compose UI?
I'm new to Compose and Android, so I may use some incorrect terminology here, but I'm basically trying to observe when a list is changed and update my UI accordingly. The list is immutable so I just want to observe when the reference changes to a new list.
class MyDataHolder {
    val myData = mutableStateOf(emptyList<MyData>())
}

myData is the list I wish to observe and is being initialized with an empty list.
In my composable, I create an instance of MyDataHolder and (attempt to) observe changes to its myData property.
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val dataHolder = MyDataHolder()
    val myData by remember { dataHolder.myData }

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        MyOtherScreen(dataHolder)
        Box {
            myData.forEach{
                Box(modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp, 60.dp)) {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dataHolder is passed to MyOtherScreen which passes dataHolder to a subclass of ImageAnalysis.Analyzer which updates the myData list continuously.
The problem I am seeing is that even when the myData list in dataHolder is updated to a non-empty list, the UI never contains any of the Box items that should be displayed for each item in the myData list (I have verified this in the Layout Inspector).
What am I be doing wrong here?

You want to use a Flow to observe in your compose function
Something like
class MyDataHolder {
    private val myData = mutableStateOf(emptyList<MyData>())
    private val _mutableMyDataStateFlow: MutableStateFlow<List<MyData>> = MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf())
    val myDataStateFlow: StateFlow<List<MyData>> = _mutableMyDataStateFlow.asStateFlow()

    fun updateData(newData: List<MyData>){
        myData = newData
        _mutableMyDataStateFlow.emit(myData)
    }
    
}

Then in your composable you listen for changes
@Composable
fun MyComposableList(myDataHolder: MyDataHolder){
    val myData = myDataHolder.myDataStateFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
    //Update your list with myData
}

Anytime you emit new data your compose function will update and myData will have the new data so just update your list with myData

Thanks for your answer. One error I'm seeing is on this line: _mutableMyDataStateFlow.emit(myData) -- "Suspend function 'emit' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function". I see from searching that there are multiple possible ways to address this. Do you have any insight into what would be the simplest?

yeah make the function a suspend function, I dont know how you are using any of this and this is just rough code I created so there will be leg work on your part to get it going

There are plenty of articles you can find on how to consume flows in jetpack compose

Making updateData a suspend function punts the same error down the road to where updateData is called. I understand that the nature of my question stems entirely from lack of knowledge on my part, so I can appreciate that you're providing direction as opposed to an exact implementation. That being said, I would like to accept your answer but it may be more helpful to future readers if the code within will compile.

at some point somewhere you need to use kotlin coroutines to run that method, I do not know how you are using this code so if you are not familiar with coroutines then you will need to familiarize yourself with that too
